# "Sticky" keyboard in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

We have a vertically scrollable page that has a **TextField** that pops up a keyboard when pressed. Is it possible to keep the keyboard on the screen while the user scrolls? If so, how?

The TextField is child to a BorderLayout Container that is ultimately child to a LayeredLayout

Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming this is in iOS? Notice that a keyboard in the border layout is a special case. Where do you scroll in a border layout and how?
You can try using `CN.putProperty("ios.VKBAlwaysOpen", "true");` or alternatively `textField.putClientProperty("asyncEditing", Boolean.TRUE);`. Not sure if it will help though.